# How to load a page/portlet on weblogic through ajax

Tags: ajax, jsf, weblogic, portlet

I have a portlet which opens a popup on click of link on it. On this **popup**, there is a three step process needs to be performed: 
1. Upload a file.
2. Review Content. 
3. Misc. tasks.

These steps are to be performed without navigating away from the page i.e. through AJAX. These pages are in JSF and have backing bean attached.
But I am having difficulty in loading portlets through AJAX.

Is there any solution for this type of scenario?

I heard of '**detached portlets**'. But I dont know whether that will help here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For making AJAX requests to your portlets your best bet is 'Resource serving' feature of JSR 286 portlets.

Please see

- [Understanding the Java Portlet Specification 2.0 (JSR 286): Part 2, Serving Resources and Other New Features](http://developers.sun.com/portalserver/reference/techart/jsr286/jsr286_2.html)
- [Resource Serving in JSR 286](https://blogs.oracle.com/satya/entry/new_feature_resource_serving_in)
- [Detached Portlets](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13155_01/wlp/docs103/portlets/building.html#wp1062431)

Also take a look at this [SO question and answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272930/how-to-submit-form-using-ajax-request-in-liferay), it's for Liferay portal, but nevertheless it should help you.