# Liferay + JSON + AJAX

Tags: java, json, liferay

I have a code

```
@RenderMapping
    public ModelAndView model(RenderRequest renderRequest, ModelMap map) {

        map.put("form", form);

        ModelAndView view = new ModelAndView("view", map);

        PortletSession portletSession = renderRequest.getPortletSession(true);
        if(portletSession != null) {  
        MappingJacksonJsonView v = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
        view.setView(v);
        view.addObject("dataListCustomer", portletSession.getAttribute("listCustomer"));
        }

        init(renderRequest, view);
        return view;
    }
```

I have an error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: application/json is not a supported mime type
    at com.liferay.portlet.MimeResponseImpl.setContentType(MimeResponseImpl.java:159)
```

Error is caused by `view.setView(v);`

How can I added listCustomer to JSON? In listCustomer I have a ModelMap

---

I have code:

```
    @ResourceMapping(value="customer")
        public ModelAndView customer(
                ResourceRequest req,
                ResourceResponse res) {

    log.debug("List Customer Resource: " + context.getCustomer());

            ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
            MappingJacksonJsonView v = new MappingJacksonJsonView();
            v.setBeanName("ajaxResult");

            mav.setView(v);
            mav.addObject("customer", context.getCustomer());

            return mav;


}
```

Customer is set in @ActionMapping function and it is OK.

In JSP I have:

```
<portlet:resourceURL escapeXml="false" id="customer" var="customer"/>
```

How can I call @ResourceMapping function? Because I don't see result of  `log.debug("List Customer Resource: " + context.getCustomer());` in logs.

Comment: See sample example of Liferay AJAX.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592144/respond-to-http-request-with-json-object-in-portlet/17593935#17593935

Comment: See sample example of Liferay AJAX.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592144/respond-to-http-request-with-json-object-in-portlet/17593935#17593935

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For ajax (with portal) you cannot use RenderMapping (or ActionMapping), you must use ResourceMapping (and if needed ResourceRequest and ResourceResponse as method parameters).

For example, not using spring but change is trivial, [see this SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272930/how-to-submit-form-using-ajax-request-in-liferay/9376240#9376240).