# Liferay ajax request and JSON response

Tags: jquery, liferay, liferay-aui

I am new in Liferay. I used service builder to create database. I populated them manually. And eventually I could call them in JSP using `PersonLocalServiceUtil class`. 
Now I want to use Ajax in my program.

For example: 
Person with attributes `personID`, `personWeight`, `personTemperature` and `datetime` are stored in database.

I want to do an ajax call by `personID` to see his **weight** or **Temperature** graph for particular timeline. All I know, I can call list from Database to controller But I don't know How can I convert it to `JSON` obejct and forward it to JSP upon request, so that JSP won't refresh the page but display new graph.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can send person id from jsp using ajax request and you can fetch data inside **controller(serveResource method)**
i.e

You need to create URL

```
<portlet:resourceURL var="resourceURL" >
</portlet:resourceURL>
```

**Ajax Call**

```
$.ajax({
  url : '${resourceURL}',
  data : data,//person id to sent
  type: 'POST',
  dataType : "json",
  success : function(data) {
    // get person data back from controller
  }
});
```

**Controller part**

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) {

    //get person id using getparameter 

    JSONObject json = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONObject();

    json.put("jsonData", "person details");
    response.getWriter().write(json.toString());

}
```

HTH

Comment: Hi Before I close the answer, I just wanted to know one more issue. Why Service Builder is not generating JsonSerializer class ? And If It was generated, could I use it directly to response http requests in controller ??

Comment: Thanks Lucky Boy! This is completely covers very common scenario.

Comment: [**respond to http request with json object in portlet**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592144/respond-to-http-request-with-json-object-in-portlet)

Answer (score 0):

```
public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) {

    Map<String, Object> data = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    data.put("test1", "test1test1test1test1test1");

    super.writeJSON(request, response, new Gson().toJson(data));
}
```