# How to pass data from page to Portlet class through AJAX call?

Tags: ajax, jsp, liferay, portlet

I'm trying to pass a value in an AJAX 'GET' request to my Portlet class, but I can't quite figure out a way to access such variable's value in the class. My AJAX code is:

```
function loadXMLDoc() 
{           
   var nocache = new Date().getTime();
   var xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
   var url = "${mURL}";
   url += '?cache=' + nocache + '&nRows=' + numberOfRows;   // Generate unique request URL
   xmlhttp.open("GET", url,true);
   xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function()
   {        
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
      { 
          document.getElementById("contentContainer").innerHTML= xmlhttp.responseText;
      } 
   }    
   xmlhttp.send();
}
```

Where 'nRows' is the variable I am trying to pass to my Portlet class.
The part of my portlet class where I attempt to retrieve the variable's value is:

```
@Override
 public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws PortletException,IOException
 {                      
     /* Returns null */
     String nRows = request.getParameter("nRows");

     response.setContentType("text");           
     response.resetBuffer();
     String htmlContent = htmlInterpreter.getParsedHTML();
     response.getWriter().print(htmlContent);
     response.flushBuffer();                                 
 }
```

Any ideas about alternatives to access the value of 'nRows' in the `serveResource(...)` method? Thanks in advance!

Comment: You have to use the *portlet namespace* as prefix for the parameter names in your URL, otherwise they will be ignored. Have a look here: https://www.liferay.com/web/meera.success/blog/-/blogs/liferay-requires-name-spaced-parameters

Comment: @Heitor Castro, Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592144/respond-to-http-request-with-json-object-in-portlet/17593935#17593935

Comment: @ParkashKumar In this case, I believe the namespace tags were also an issue, but I do appreciate the alternative resource! Thank you, Andrea, for your answer as well!

Comment: Are you using aui tags?

Comment: Actually not, but since I had forgotten to use the '<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>' and '<portlet:namespace/>' before my parameter, I wasn't able to access my nRows variable, even using the ParamUtil.getString() functionality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use liferay's `<portlet:resourceURL var="resourceURL"> </portlet:resourceURL>`  with **AlloyUI** instead of using simple `xmlhttp` function.

Change required namespace parameter in your **liferay-portlet.xml**

```
<requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters>
```

**Add following import**

```
    <%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet" prefix="portlet" %>
<portlet:defineObjects />
```

**Change the url to below**

```
url += '?cache=' + nocache + '&<portlet:namespace/>nRows=' + numberOfRows;
```

Please find below code to get a parameter using **ParamUtil**:

```
@Override
 public void serveResource(ResourceRequest request, ResourceResponse response) throws PortletException,IOException
 {                      
     /* Returns null */
     String nRows = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "nRows");

     response.setContentType("text");           
     response.resetBuffer();
     String htmlContent = htmlInterpreter.getParsedHTML();
     response.getWriter().print(htmlContent);
     response.flushBuffer();                                 
 }
```

For more details put your eyes on this link:

http://liferayway.blogspot.in/2013/08/ajaxjsonliferay-example.html

Hope it may help you.!!