# Liferay ajax call for dependent select boxes

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, jsp, liferay

I'm having this problem where I need to fill a select box with records,, when I choose a province from the first select box, the second select box should be dynamically filled with the cities in that province..

so this is what I did, I made a table that contains the cities and created a finderImpl for that,, here's the contents (imports not included)

```
public class m_city_municipalityFinderImpl extends BasePersistenceImpl<m_city_municipality> implements m_city_municipalityFinder{
    public List<m_city_municipality> getCityMunicipalityByProvinceId(long province_id){
        Session session = null;
        try{
            session = openSession();
            String sql = CustomSQLUtil.get("cityMunicipalitySQLQuery");
            SQLQuery queryObject = session.createSQLQuery(sql);
            queryObject.setCacheable(false);
            queryObject.addEntity("m_city_municipality", m_city_municipalityImpl.class);
            QueryPos queryPos = QueryPos.getInstance(queryObject);
            queryPos.add(province_id);

            return (List<m_city_municipality>) queryObject.list();
        }catch(Exception e){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }finally{
            closeSession(session);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

then I used liferay's built-in functions to implement ajax using AUI,, here're the codes in my jsp and action portlet

**JSP** (the script is written at the bottom)

```
<%@page import="com.sampleportlet.services.service.m_provinceLocalServiceUtil"%>
<%@page import="com.sampleportlet.services.model.m_province"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionErrors"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.servlet.SessionMessages"%>
<%@page import="com.sampleportlet.services.model.personal_contact_present" %>
<%@page import="com.sampleportlet.services.service.personal_contact_presentLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@page import="com.sampleportlet.services.model.personal_contact_permanent" %>
<%@page import="com.sampleportlet.services.service.personal_contact_permanentLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@page import="com.sampleportlet.services.model.business_contact" %>
<%@page import="com.sampleportlet.services.service.business_contactLocalServiceUtil" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContext" %>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.service.ServiceContextThreadLocal" %>
<%@page import="javax.portlet.PortletURL"%>
<%@page import="com.liferay.portal.kernel.util.Validator"%>
<%@page import="java.util.List"%>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://alloy.liferay.com/tld/aui" prefix="aui"%>

<%@ taglib uri="http://liferay.com/tld/ui" prefix="liferay-ui" %>
<%@ taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/portlet_2_0" prefix="portlet" %>
<script src="js/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>

<portlet:defineObjects />

<portlet:actionURL var="ADDFClassActionURL" windowState="normal" name="saveContactDetails">
</portlet:actionURL>

<portlet:resourceURL var="resourceURL" ></portlet:resourceURL>

<% if(SessionMessages.contains(renderRequest.getPortletSession(),"success")){%>
<liferay-ui:success key="success" message="Information has been successfully updated." />
<%} %>
<% if(SessionErrors.contains(renderRequest.getPortletSession(),"error")){%>
<liferay-ui:error key="error" message="There is an Error occured while updating your record. Please try again" />
<%} %>

<form action="<%=ADDFClassActionURL%>" name="contactDetails_form" method="POST" role="form">
<div class="main-content-body">
    <center><h3>APPOINTIVE DIRECTOR DATA FORM</h3></center>
    <div class=" row main-form">
        <h5 class="header">Personal Contact Details</h5>
        <div class="col-md-12 header"><strong>PRESENT ADDRESS</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pres_home_no_street"><span>* </span>Home No. &amp; Street</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>pres_home_no_street" id="<portlet:namespace/>pres_home_no_street" value="<%= pres_home_no_street%>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pres_province"><span>* </span>Province</label>
                <select class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>pres_province" id="<portlet:namespace/>pres_province" value="<%= pres_province %>">
                <%
                    java.util.List<m_province> provinceList = m_provinceLocalServiceUtil.getm_provinces(0, m_provinceLocalServiceUtil.getm_provincesCount());
                    for (m_province i : provinceList) {
                %>
                    <option value="<%=i.getProvince_id()%>"><%=i.getProvince()%></option>
                <%
                    }
                %>
                </select>

             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pres_city_municipality"><span>* </span>City/Municipality</label>
                <select class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>pres_city_municipality" id="<portlet:namespace/>pres_city_municipality" value="<%= pres_city_municipality %>"></select>
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="vertical-align:top;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pres_zipcode">Zip Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>pres_zipcode" id="<portlet:namespace/>pres_zipcode" value="<%= pres_zipcode %>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="pres_telno"><span>* </span>Tel. No.</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>pres_telno" id="<portlet:namespace/>pres_telno" value="<%= pres_telno %>">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 header"><strong>PERMANENT ADDRESS</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="perm_home_no_street"><span>* </span>Home No. &amp; Street</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>perm_home_no_street" id="<portlet:namespace/>perm_home_no_street" value="<%= perm_home_no_street %>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="perm_province"><span>* </span>Province</label>
                <select class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>perm_province" id="<portlet:namespace/>perm_province" value="<%= perm_province %>"  onchange="listMunicipality(this)">
                <%
                    for (m_province i : provinceList) {
                %>
                    <option value="<%=i.getProvince_id()%>"><%=i.getProvince()%></option>
                <%
                    }
                %>
                </select>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="perm_city_municipality"><span>* </span>City/Municipality</label>
                <select class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>perm_city_municipality" id="<portlet:namespace/>perm_city_municipality" value="<%= perm_city_municipality %>"  onchange="listMunicipality(this)"></select>
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="perm_email"><span>* </span>Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>perm_email" id="<portlet:namespace/>perm_email" value="<%= perm_email %>">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="vertical-align:top;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="perm_zipcode">Zip Code</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>perm_zipcode" id="<portlet:namespace/>perm_zipcode" value="<%= perm_zipcode %>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="perm_telno">Tel. No.</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>perm_telno" id="<portlet:namespace/>perm_telno" value="<%= perm_telno %>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="perm_celno"><span>* </span>Cel. No.</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>perm_celno" id="<portlet:namespace/>perm_celno" value="<%= perm_celno %>">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-12 header"><strong>BUSINESS CONTACT DETAILS</strong></div>
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bus_company_name">Company Name</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>bus_company_name" id="<portlet:namespace/>bus_company_name" value="<%= bus_company_name %>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bus_address">Permanent Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>bus_address" id="<portlet:namespace/>bus_address" value="<%= bus_address %>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bus_email">Email Address</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>bus_email" id="<portlet:namespace/>bus_email" value="<%= bus_email %>">
             </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-6" style="vertical-align:top;">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bus_personal_telno">Tel. No</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>bus_personal_telno" id="<portlet:namespace/>bus_personal_telno" value="<%= bus_personal_telno %>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bus_telno">Tel. No.</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>bus_telno" id="<portlet:namespace/>bus_telno" value="<%= bus_telno %>">
             </div>
             <div class="form-group">
                <label for="bus_celno">Cel. No.</label>
                <input type="text" class="form-control medium" name="<portlet:namespace/>bus_celno" id="<portlet:namespace/>bus_celno" value="<%= bus_celno %>">
             </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

<aui:script>
AUI().use('aui-base','aui-io-request','aui-node', function(A){
    A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>pres_province").on('change',function(){       
        A.io.request('<%=resourceURL%>', {
             method: 'POST',
             data: { 
                "<portlet:namespace/>provinceName" : A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>pres_province").val()
             },
             dataType: 'json',
             on: {
                 success: function() {
                    var citiesList =this.get('responseData');   //on success fuction we will get response data
                    A.one('#<portlet:namespace />pres_city_municipality').empty();
                    //using for loop we iterating the list
                    for(var i in citiesList){
                        A.one('#<portlet:namespace />pres_city_municipality').append("<option value='"+ citiesList[i] +"' >"+citiesList[i]+"</option> ");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
    A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>perm_province").on('change',function(){       
        A.io.request('<%=resourceURL%>', {
             method: 'POST',
             data: { 
                "<portlet:namespace/>provinceName" : A.one("#<portlet:namespace/>perm_province").val()
             },
             dataType: 'json',
             on: {
                 success: function() {
                    var citiesList =this.get('responseData');   //on success fuction we will get response data
                    A.one('#<portlet:namespace />perm_city_municipality').empty();
                    //using for loop we iterating the list
                    for(var i in citiesList){
                        A.one('#<portlet:namespace />perm_city_municipality').append("<option value='"+ citiesList[i] +"' >"+citiesList[i]+"</option> ");
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</aui:script>



<div class="buttons">
    <button id="edit" class="edit">Edit</button>
    <input class="save" type="submit" name="saveContactDetails" id="saveContactDetails" value="Save"/>
</div>
</form>
```

**Action Portlet Class** (only written is the serveResource method)

```
public static Log log = LogFactoryUtil.getLog(ActionClass.class);

    @Override
    public void serveResource(ResourceRequest resourceRequest, ResourceResponse resourceResponse) throws IOException, PortletException {
        try {

            //contact details
            String provinceName = ParamUtil.getString(resourceRequest, "provinceName");
            log.info("PROVINCE HERE::::::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+ provinceName);
            System.out.println("PROVINCE HERE::::::>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>> "+ provinceName);

            JSONArray city_municipalityArray = JSONFactoryUtil.createJSONArray();
            List<m_city_municipality> citiesList = m_city_municipalityFinderUtil.getCityMunicipalityByProvinceId(Long.parseLong(provinceName));

            System.out.println(citiesList);
            for(m_city_municipality m : citiesList){
                city_municipalityArray.put(m.getCity_municipality());
            }

            PrintWriter writer = resourceResponse.getWriter();
            writer.write(city_municipalityArray.toString());
            writer.println(city_municipalityArray.toString());
            writer.flush();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            log.error(e);
        }
    }
```

I ran this but what I get is a null pointer exception, and also the combo box show weird stuff, sorry I dont have enough reputation to attach an image of it..

what seems to be my problem with this? can you point out what's wrong with my code?

Comment: Code looks pretty good! At what point are you getting null pointer exception?

Comment: The only issue I see is request parameter's name. It should be just provinceName instead of <portlet:namespace/>provinceName.

Comment: Where have you defined onchange="listMunicipality(this)" script function?

Comment: I'll update the post, the listMunicipality(this) part is not used,, I experimented on it but didn't delete after,,,,,,,,, o yeah I actually found out that the query/finder returns null value,, I tried displaying the returned list but contents aren't there..

Comment: Ok, so it means you have figured it out.

Comment: yes I think the answer lies in how I treat the finder to retrieve records..... the question I have in mind now is, what is the most efective way of monitoring/tracking how data is retrieved on the mvcportlet class... I really cant see the data unless I display it on the javascript... right now what I wanted to do is to display the data when I pass the finderImpl class... to at least pinpoint where and how the null comes out

Comment: You can enable logging to track data being transferred from finder to action. Moreover, you need to add null check on citiesList, if citiesList is null write specified message to confirm empty list on UI. Disable city dropdown, if required. Also, you can give additional option to add city for selected province, if there isn't any.

Comment: okay then, I'll post progress later.

Comment: Sure, happy coding!!!

Comment: hey sir, I have a problem still with the code, apparently it returns the wrong information, I tested it using firebug and the post parameter is really being sent, however the response doesn't contain what should be returned by serveResource().... instead it returned the html code of my jsp,,, what is up with that??  instead of filling up the select box with the responseData, it's been filled with unneeded html,,,, I tried all that I could, even tinkering with liferay-portlet.xml and the namespaces, but no luck til now,,, please help guys.... badly need help

Comment: even if it means I should change the code entirely, I would,,, even that I tried,,, but nothing came closer than this approach for me,,,,,,, help please

Comment: Does this return proper results?
return (List<m_city_municipality>) queryObject.list();

Comment: when I tried directly retrieving from it,, yes it does return proper results,,, problem is that when I send ajax request, the response is different,,,,, the thing that bothered me the most is that I think the ajax doesnt go into serveresource in the first place,,, because I tried commenting the serveresource code,, but the response is still the same,, even though it shouldnt return anything at all,,,

Comment: I have updated my answer by adding javascript call to onchange of province dropdown. Add debugger in javascript method and see if proper province value is being passed. Then add debugger in serveResource to see if this method gets called and forms proper JSON. After that, check the returned data in javascript.

Comment: the data is correct, but when I use ajax, as it passed through serveResource, the data returned is very different, it is in html and from what I noticed, it is the html code of my jsp page,,,, why is that? I'll look into it on firebug...

Comment: on firebug, the post is ok,the parameter is being passed ok,,,, but the response isn't correct

Comment: yes I have tried your code,, still the same,,, being suspicious of this,I even commented all codes inside serveresource, then emptied my cache but it still returns the stuff..... I think this is a whole other issue..

Comment: Have you tried adding <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters> in your liferay-portlet.xml?

Comment: Can you provide your complete portlet code, so that I may investigate it locally?

Comment: I have already answer for simple ajax call structure in liferay. You can see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17592144/respond-to-http-request-with-json-object-in-portlet/17593935#17593935

Comment: yes I tried the <requires-namespaced-parameters>false</requires-namespaced-parameters> ,, and also the <ajaxable>true</ajaxable>

Comment: wait, I'll try the link you posted first,,, If it doesnt work I'll show you the codes,,

Comment: Ok, give it a best try. Otherwise, the only option is to have complete code and investigate it.

Comment: I have tried and failed again... can you check the code now please? what other codes do you need? how do I give it to you? by email?

Comment: Send your complete portlet via email to parkash-kumar@hotmail.com