# Return Html Snippet with by Ajax

Tags: liferay-6

I am trying to send the HTML response form the Ajax Call. Exactly I want to render a JSP and return the resulted HTML String as the response.
I tried to follow the steps given in the following post. https://www.liferay.com/community/forums/-/message_boards/message/4940181 
But I could not found the methods in PortalUtil class. 
I am using LR6.2.

Comment: its answered here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9272930/how-to-submit-form-using-ajax-request-in-liferay

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be done by including a jsp in the response.

```
 getPortletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/WEB-INF/jsp/html.jsp").include(p_request, p_response);
```

Once the control is passed to the JSP, it will act like the normal JSPs, you can get the vales from request and go ahead with the manipulations.